# How to convert a date in this format (Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2010) to a Java Date (The string comes from an alfresco property)

Tags: java, alfresco, date-parsing

i'm managing a date that comes from an Alfresco Properties and is in the specified (Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2010) and i need to convert it to a Java date...i've looked around and found millions of posts for various string to date conversion form and also [this page](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/) and so i tried something like this:

```
private static final DateFormat alfrescoDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date dataRispostaDate = alfrescoDateFormat.parse(dataRisposta);
```

But it throws an exception.(The exception is (SSollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione della data: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011").

I post the complete code:

```
        try {
            QName currDocTypeQName = (QName) nodeService.getType(doc);
            log.error("QName:["+currDocTypeQName.toString()+"]");
            if (currDocTypeQName != null) {
                String codAtto = AlfrescoConstants.getCodAttoFromQName(currDocTypeQName.toString());
                log.error("codAtto:["+codAtto+"]");
                if (codAtto.equals(AlfrescoConstants.COD_IQT)){
                    List<ChildAssociationRef> risposteAssociate = nodeService.getChildAssocs(doc, AlfrescoConstants.QN_RISPOSTEASSOCIATE, RegexQNamePattern.MATCH_ALL);
                    for (ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef : risposteAssociate) {
                        // Vado a prendere il nodo
                        NodeRef risposta = childAssocRef.getChildRef();
                        String dataRisposta = (nodeService.getProperty(risposta, AlfrescoConstants.QN_DATA_RISPOSTA)).toString();
                        log.error("dataRisposta:["+dataRisposta+"]");
                        if (!dataRisposta.isEmpty()){
                            try {
                                Date dataDa = dmyFormat.parse(req.getParameter("dataDa"));
                                log.error("dataDa:["+dataDa.toString()+"]");
                                Date dataA = dmyFormat.parse(req.getParameter("dataA"));
                                log.error("dataA:["+dataA.toString()+"]");
                                Date dataRispostaDate = alfrescoDateFormat.parse(dataRisposta);
                                log.error("dataRispostaDate:["+dataRispostaDate.toString()+"]");

                                if (dataRispostaDate.after(dataDa) && dataRispostaDate.before(dataA)){
                                    results.add(doc);
                                    log.error("La data risposta  è compresa tra le date specificate");
                                }else{
                                    log.error("La data risposta non è compresa tra le date specificate");
                                }
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                log.error("Sollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione della data: " + e);
                                throw new RuntimeException("Formato data non valido");
                            }
                        }else{
                            log.error("La data risposta non è specificata");
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    results.add(doc);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Sollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione del codice atto nel webscript nicola: " + e);
        }
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Couldy ou expand on "it doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: It throws an exception. Should be a parse exception but i'll check to be sure!

Comment: I tried that format with the string you provided, and got an appropriate response, with no exception. Can you include the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: @Nicola: For questions like this, *always* include all the relevant information for exceptions - the type and the error message.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i'm new to java, i think there is no stack trace because it's inside a try-catch block, how can i print the stack trace in the catch block?

Comment: @Nicola Assuming that "log" is log4j or java.util.logging, change the line in the catch block to: log.error(""Sollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione del codice atto nel webscript nicola", e);

Comment: Sollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione della data: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011"
This is the exception

Comment: Of course it also catches "Sollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione del codice atto nel webscript nicola: java.lang.RuntimeException: Formato data non valido"

Comment: What's the data type of AlfrescoConstants.QN_DATA_RISPOSTA in your data model? If it's a cm:Date, then you should just be able to cast the property to a Java date

Comment: its defined like this:
<property name="crl:data_risposta">
    <title>Data risposta</title>
     <type>d:date</type>
</property>
You mean the this should work?
Date dataRisposta = (Date)(nodeService.getProperty(risposta, AlfrescoConstants.QN_DATA_RISPOSTA));

Comment: @Gagravarr you are right, it works!If you answer the thread i'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Nicola Glad it worked! I've added it as an answer

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti can you please mark JMelnik's answer as accepted? Gragravarr's answer is to localized. Similar problem happend to me outside Alfresco so Gragravarr's answer was useless. JMelnik's worked.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Basically your **problem is** that you are using a [SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) constructor, where javadoc says:

> Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using
>   the given pattern and the default date
>   format symbols for the **default locale**.

And if you try using this code:

```
DateFormat osLocalizedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM EEEE");
System.out.println(osLocalizedDateFormat.format(new Date()))
```

you will notice that it prints you month and day of the week titles based on your locale.

**Solution to your problem is** to override default Date locale using [SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) constructor:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
dateFormat.parse("Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. @Nicola, is your default locale Italian?

Comment: yes it is. I think this is a really good suggestion.I've marked the other one as answer because my issue was "Alfresco Related" and the other answer is much cleaner in my situation, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: IDK whats happening with this code, what I just wanted was for my input of 2019/05/05 be save on the DB as 2019/05/05. But when running what was being save on the parse date, im receiving with a format like this "Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011" but what was being save on the DB is 2019/05/05. I'm confused as to why the actual value I know should be saved is different from what is being saved on the DB, or is there some hidden processes going around?. Anyhow now my date now parses correctly, so great. thx..

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(                     // Produce a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` object.
    "Wed Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011" ,    // Corrected `Tue` to `Wed`.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , Locale.US  ) 
)
```

> 2011-07-13T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]

## Bad data: `Wed` vs `Tue`

You input string `Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011` is invalid. July 13 of 2011 was a Wednesday, **not a Tuesday**.

```
String input = "Wed Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011" ;  // Corrected `Tue` to `Wed`.
```

[image: screen shot of July 2011 calendar in Duck Duck Go search engine]

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes seen in other Answers.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input string. Notice the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), which defines the human language to be used in parsing name of month and name of day-of-week.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , Locale.US  );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f  );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2011-07-13T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]

## Time zone

Your [`CEST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time) is a pseudo-zone, not a true time zone. Never use these. They are not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

The `ZonedDateTime` class will make a valiant effort at guessing the intention behind such a 3-4 character pseudo-zone. Your `CEST` happened to work here, interpreted as [`Europe/Paris`](https://time.is/Paris) time zone. But you cannot rely on the guess being 100% successful. Instead, **avoid such pseudo-zones entirely**.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of **`continent/region`**, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );  // https://time.is/Paris
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );  // Current date varies around the globe by zone.
```

## ISO 8601

Your input string’s format is terrible. When serializing date-time values as text, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

The `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends the standard format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets as seen in examples above.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time (JSR 310) classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comments, I believe that your property is actually of type *d:date* or *d:datetime*. If so, the property will already be coming back from Alfresco as a java Date object. So, all you'd need to do is:

```
  NodeRef risposta = childAssocRef.getChildRef();
  Date dataRisposta = (Date)nodeService.getProperty(risposta, AlfrescoConstants.QN_DATA_RISPOSTA);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that CEST is not a timezone Java supports. You can use "CST".

The Javadoc for TimeZone notes:

> Three-letter time zone IDs
>   For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, **their use is deprecated** because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

For three/four letter timezone support I suggest you try JodaTime which may do a better job.

---

```
String dataRisposta = "Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CST 2010";
Date dataRispostaDate = alfrescoDateFormat.parse(dataRisposta);
System.out.println(dataRispostaDate);
```

prints

```
Tue Jul 13 07:00:00 BST 2010
```

---

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
Arrays.sort(ids);
for (String id : ids) {
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

prints

```
...
CAT
CET
CNT
CST
CST6CDT
CTT
...
```

Comment: The problem is that the string is a property of an alfresco Node.
I take it with:
String dataRisposta = (nodeService.getProperty(risposta, AlfrescoConstants.QN_DATA_RISPOSTA)).toString();

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception for me.  If you know you want `CEST` to mean `CST` or some other time-zone you can use `.replaceAll("CEST", "CST")`

Comment: I don't think that this answer is right. The spec for SimpleDateFormat (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) says that "For parsing, RFC 822 time zones are also accepted." These are 4 letter time zones; I assume that CEST is one of these. When I ran the example, it worked fine without complaining about the time zone format, and returned a reasonable result.

Comment: @Sean Reilly, I assume you didn't read my whole answer "CEST is NOT a supported time zone in Oracle Java 6 update 23.  It doesn't give me an error either, it just gives me the time in the local timezone.

Comment: in my log i have errors every time i try to parse that date also if it has CET:
Sollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione della data: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2011"
or
Sollevata un'eccezione durante la gestione della data: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jun 23 00:00:00 CEST 2010"

Comment: @Nicola, Both parse for me. I suspect you are using an older version of Java. Which version do you have?

Comment: @Sean Reilly, the four digit timezone consists of "Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes"  but not letters.

Comment: From the log i get:
15:11:37,172  INFO  [service.descriptor.DescriptorService] Alfresco JVM - v1.6.0_16-b01; maximum heap size 938,688MB

Comment: I would try Java 6 update 25 if you can. Update 16 may be old enough to have a problem with this.

Comment: @Peter: I did read the entire answer, but I'm not sure that I agree with it. There's no guarantee that TimeZone and SimpleDateFormat support the same list of time zones; SimpleDateFormat explicitly lists specific formats that it will support for parsing but not for formatting, so it's entirely reasonable that it might support extra stuff not included in TimeZone. More importantly, I *tried it and got it to work* (With 1.6.0_24 for osx, btw). It certainly seems like a reasonable time zone to parse -- it is an official time zone name.

Comment: FYI for those who don't live in europe: CEST != CET, and CEST != CST. CEST is a central european time zone with daylight saving time (Central European Summer Time), and is equivalent to GMT + 2. Certainly converting CEST -> CST is not right.

Comment: @Sean, Sorry for getting annoyed. I have been meaning to download Java 6 update 25. It may be that an update is all that is required. ;)

Comment: @Peter: No worries. If it does work on 6.0_24+ and not earlier, then I will be annoyed (but not with you). Is it just me, or is this starting to feel like a java/portability bug?

Comment: Updating didn't work, but it worked using this line:
Date dataRisposta = (Date)(nodeService.getProperty(risposta, AlfrescoConstants.QN_DATA_RISPOSTA));

Comment: In other words there was no need to parse it. That did cross my mind. ;)

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function I had the same issue.

```
public String getMyDate(String myDate, String requiredFormat, String mycurrentFormat) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(returnFormat);
    Date date = null;
    String returnValue = "";
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(myDate);
        returnValue = dateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        returnValue = myDate;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Example:

Wed May 06 13:01:29 EDT 2020 i.e  "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" is mycurrentFormat

4.May.2020 i.e. "d.MMM.yyyy" is my requiredFormat

```
Date date = new Date();

getMyDate(date.toString(), "d.MMM.yyyy", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy")
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also your code is longer than the code in most of the other answers. Has it got any advantages over those?