# How can I convert Date.toString back to Date?

Tags: java

I have a string obtained by calling the `toString` method of an instance of the class Date. How can I get a Date object from this string?

```
Date d = new Date();
String s = d.toString;
Date theSameDate = ...
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried to use SimpleDateFormat, but I get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date`
What is the date format produced by Date.toString ()?

Comment: Try parsing with, say, `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Do not use the String. Keep the Date object and only transform to String when needed.

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide some context on what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Do not use `Date`. The modern approach uses `java.time.Instant` and standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for the string. See the [correct Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205424/642706).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a date in this format (Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2010) to a Java Date (The string comes from an alfresco property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937017/how-to-convert-a-date-in-this-format-tue-jul-13-000000-cest-2010-to-a-java-d)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your real goal is to serialize a `Date` object for some kind of custom made persistence or data transfer, a simple solution would be:

```
Date d = new Date();
long l = d.getTime();
Date theSameDate = new Date(l);
```

Comment: FYI: The troublesome` Date` Class is now legacy, replaced by `Instant` and the other *java.time* classes. See the modern approach in  [this Answer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by Ole V.V.

Answer (score 20):

You could do it like this

```
Date d = new Date();
String s = d.toString;
Date theSameDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(s);
```

Comment: This method also works with org.json library when converting Java Date objects to and from JSONObjects using the bean constructor, since it uses Date.toString() when constructing JSONObjects. Thank you for this, it's exactly the format for SimpleDateFormat that I was looking for.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old classes used here are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the gist/idea?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 10 years ago"*

Answer (score 6):

1. If your real goal is to serialize and deserialize a date and time (for data transfer or for persistence, for example), serialize to ISO 8601, the standard format for date and time data.
2. Skip the long outdated `Date` class. The modern Java date and time API known as `java.time` is so much nicer to work with. The class you need from it is probably `Instant` (this depends on your more exact requirements).

The two points go nicely hand in hand:

```
    Instant i = Instant.now();
    String s = i.toString();
    Instant theSameInstant = Instant.parse(s);
```

The modern classes’ `toString` methods produce ISO 8601 format (e.g., `2018-01-11T10:59:45.036Z`), and their `parse` methods read the same format back. So this snippet is all you need, and you get an instant equal to the first, with nanosecond precision.

If you cannot control the string you get, and you get the result from `Date.toString()`, the format pattern string in [Sedalb’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574010/5772882) works with `java.time` too:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
    Date d = new Date();
    String s = d.toString();
    Instant nearlyTheSameInstant = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, dtf).toInstant();
```

It’s essential to provide a locale. Otherwise the JVM’s default locale will be used, and if it’s not English, parsing will fail. In the worst case you will see your code running fine for many years and suddenly it will break when one day someone runs it on a computer or device with a different locale setting.

The point from [jambjo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9431983/5772882) still applies: The three and four letter time zone abbreviations used in `Date.toString()` are *very* often ambiguous, so there is no guarantee that the time zone is interpreted correctly, and again, it will be interpreted differently on different JVMs.

Finally, `Date.toString()` does not render the milliseconds that the `Date` holds, which leads to an inaccuracy of up to 999 milliseconds. If using the string from `Date.toString()`, there is nothing we can do about it (which was why I named the variable `nearlyTheSameInstant`).

Comment: tl;dr `Instant.parse( Instant.now().toString() )`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat#parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29). It should provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: That class is now outmoded by `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score -1):

`Date theSameDate = new Date(Date.parse(s));`

For some not so obvious reasons, this is not a particularly good idea. You can find details on that in the API documentation for the parse method. One problem is e.g. that the time zone abbreviations are ambiguous, so that the parser may fail in interpreting the correct time zone.

Comment: Also `Date.parse()` was deprecated a long time ago.