# String to OffsetDateTime parse in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time

I am trying to parse date string to `OffsetDateTime` as below.

But I am getting below exception,

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012' could not be parsed at index 0

```
public class ParseExample {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
        String dateStr = "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012";
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr));
    }
}
```

can someone please help me with this mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can, avoid relying on parsing a three letter time zone abbreviation like `IST`. You may get Icelandic standard time, Irish summer time, Israel standard time or something else.

Comment: It may look like you’ve got the result of calling `toString` on an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object? If so, it is better to convert the `Date` to `OffsetDateTime` than to parse its `toString`. `yourOldfashionedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime()`.

Comment: Related: [How to convert Date.toString back to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431927/how-to-convert-date-tostring-back-to-date) There’s a longer list of linked questions to the right, you may want to go through it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## `ZonedDateTime`

*Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012* should be a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), you can parse it with a custom [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), then convert it to [`OffsetDateTime`](http://OffsetDateTime):

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, format).toOffsetDateTime();
```

Comment: You should add a note about the risks inherent in trying to parse a non-unique pseudo-zone such as `IST`. Could be India Standard Time, Ireland Standard Time, or others. Instead use real time zone names in standardized `Continent/Region` format such as `Asia/Kolkata`.