# OffsetDateTime String Comparision with OffsetDateTime.now() in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, compareto

I am very new to OffsetDateTime usage and I am trying to compare OffsetDateTime strings with OffsetDateTime.now() in java this way,

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class OffsetDateTimeDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      OffsetDateTime one = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-02-03T12:30:30+01:00");
      System.out.println("First ::" + OffsetDateTime.now().compareTo(one));

      OffsetDateTime date1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-02-14T00:00:00");
      System.out.println("Second ::" +  OffsetDateTime.now().compareTo(date1));

      OffsetDateTime date3 = OffsetDateTime.parse("Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012");
      System.out.println(" Third :: " +OffsetDateTime.now().compareTo(date3));


   }
}
```

But I am getting  java.time.format.DateTimeParseException in all the 3 cases.

However if i compare 2 OffsetDateTime Strings with CompareTo method its working fine.

Can someone shed some light to me in this regard and kindly guide me through my mistake.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your second date-string has no offset

Comment: And the third input cannot be parsed to `OffsetDateTime` but to `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild tried as you suggested. Is this is right?  String date3 = "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012";
      DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
      OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date3, format).toOffsetDateTime();
      System.out.println("offsetDateTime ::" + offsetDateTime);
      System.out.println(" offsetDateTime  compareTo :: " +OffsetDateTime.now().compareTo(offsetDateTime));

Comment: @Meno Hochschild but it is always returning 1 only

Comment: @user1660325 That’s as I would expect since “now” is after the parsed date-time in all cases. As an aside, “The comparison is based on the instant then on the local date-time.” ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#compareTo-java.time.OffsetDateTime-)) Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Don’t rely on parsing `IST` as a time zone. You may get Iceland time, Irish summer time, Israel standard time or India Standard Time (these are the possibilities I know of, there may be more).

Answer (score 5):

Your `compareTo` coding is a distraction. Your exception is about parsing the string inputs into objects.

Another problem: You are using wrong classes on the 2nd and 3rd inputs.

Another problem: You are relying implicitly on your JVM’s current default time zone when calling `now()`. Poor practice as any programmer reading will not know if you intended the default or if you were unaware of the issue as are so many programmers. Furthermore, the current default can be changed at any moment during runtime by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM. So better to always specify explicitly your desired/expected zone or offset.

```
OffsetDateTime.now( 
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)
```

Or better yet, use a `ZonedDateTime` to capture more information than a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
)
```

## First: `OffsetDateTime` works

Your first string input is proper, and parses successfully.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-02-03T12:30:30+01:00" )
```

Full line of code:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-02-03T12:30:30+01:00" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://odt.toString():%202017-02-03T12:30:30+01:00).

> odt.toString(): 2017-02-03T12:30:30+01:00

To compare, extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Doing so effectively adjusts your moment from some offset to an offset of zero, or UTC itself. An `Instant` is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;                          // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
boolean odtIsPast = odt.toInstant().isBefore( instant ) ;
```

## Second: `LocalDateTime`

Your second string input lacks any indicator of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). So an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) is the wrong class to use. Instead use `LocalDateTime` which lacks any concept of offset or zone.

This means a `LocalDateTime` **cannot** represent a moment. For example, noon on the 23rd of January this year could mean noon on `Asia/Tokyo` which would be hours earlier than noon in `Europe/Paris`, or it could mean noon in `America/Montreal` which would be a moment even more hours later. Without the context of a zone or offset, a `LocalDateTime` has no real meaning. So **comparing a `LocalDateTime` to the current moment is senseless**.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-02-14T00:00:00" )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://odt.toString():%202017-02-03T12:30:30+01:00).

> ldt.toString(): 2019-02-14T00:00

To compare, you can’t — illogical as discussed above. You must assign a time zone (or offset) to determine a moment on the timeline. If you know *for certain* this date and time were meant for a specific time zone, assign `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Then extract a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to compare.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;                   // India time.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;                          // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
boolean zdtIsPast = zdt.toInstant().isBefore( instant ) ;  // Compare.
```

By the way, I noticed the time-of-day is zero. If your goal was to represent the date only, without any time-of-day and without any zone, use `LocalDate` class.

## Third: Don’t bother, ambiguous input

Your third string input carries a time zone indicator. So it should be parsed as a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Unfortunately, you’ve chosen a ***terrible* string format** to parse. Never use the 2-4 character pseudo-zones like `IST`. They are not standardized. And they are not unique! Your `IST` could mean *Ireland Standard Time* or *India Standard Time* or others.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://odt.toString():%202017-02-03T12:30:30+01:00).

> zdt.toString(): 2019-02-20T22:34:26.833+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

You could *try* to parse this. [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) will make a guess as to which zone was meant by `IST`. But it would be just a guess, and so is unreliable given the inherently ambiguous input. Personally, I would refuse to code that, rejecting this input data back to its source.

If you insist on making this unreliable parse attempt, see [the correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734993/642706) to a [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54734921/642706) you asked recently.

Educate your source about always using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats to exchange date-time values as human-readable text.

The *java.time* classes use these [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends the standard to append the standard name of the time zone in square brackets.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).