# Convert String value to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, java-time, offsetdatetime

I have the following code:

```
   public class Objc{
    
    OffsetDateTime purchaseDate = new OffsetDateTime();
    
    // getter/setter
    }
    ....
    String buyDate = ......;
    
    objc.setPurchaseDate (new OffsetDateTime(buyDate));
```

How to convert String to `OffsetDateTime` object properly?

Comment: [Convert string to OffsetDateTime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297939/convert-string-to-offsetdatetime-in-java)

Comment: [String to OffsetDateTime parse in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734921/string-to-offsetdatetime-parse-in-java)

Comment: [OffsetDateTime parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048032/offsetdatetime-parsing)

Comment: I checked the post but I see multiple solutions. Can you paste here the correct one, please?