# Unable to format string-date of format `Sun Apr 10 21:26:54 +05:30 2022` in java

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

In java,

**Unable to parse date-Strings of this format `Sun Apr 10 21:26:54 +05:30 2022`.**

I am using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse this String.

The pattern that i'm using : `E MMM dd hh:mm:ss X yyyy`

I'm mainly unable to work if the timezone (+05:30) is present before the year-value.

`X` seems to work only if it is at the end of the String.

I have tried `Z`, but it doesn't work.

Sample code :

```
String dateStr = "Sun Apr 10 21:26:54 +05:30 2022";
java.util.Date epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss X yyyy")
                .parse(dateStr);
```

Error im getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Apr 10 21:26:54 +05:30 2022"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at com.company.ExifDataExtractor.main(ExifDataExtractor.java:51)
```

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. It was a notoriously troublesome class and is fortunately long outdated. Use java.time, the modern java date and time API.

Comment: Under the linked original question i am immodest enough to recommend [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205424/5772882).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "X" 3 times for this format according the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

> Offset X and x: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'. Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'. Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'. Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException. Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.

```
java.util.Date epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss XXX yyyy").parse(dateStr);
```

Comment: this one worked.. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateDormat` is very outdated and bug prone class. It is deprecated. I strongly recommend not to use it. (The same goes for class `Date`) Please switch to `java.time` package available since java 8. Read about and use class [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)