# How to sort the dates from current to old date in Android or Java?

Tags: java, android, date

I am in a need of function, user defined, which could sort the dates from current time to old time.

I'm having list of 10 dates which I want to sort these dates starting from last recent date.

Currently I have a logic, in which if we can covert the **date in milli-second** then comparing it with current-milli-seconds and the least milli-second will be the recent date.
That is,

```
CURRENT_MILLI_SECOND - A_DATE_CONVERTED_TO_MILLI_SECONDS = MILLI-SECONDS
```

Please suggest me if anyone can help me in this logic or any other logics...!!!

This is the formate which I am getting from server:

```
Thu Dec 27 11:02:43 GMT+05:30 2012
```

Comment: @hotveryspicy how to convert the above Thu Dec 27 11:02:43 GMT+05:30 2012 to Date format.

Comment: @ricintech http://stackoverflow.com/a/5937963/739270 example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go with [**Comparator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and can sort data by using [compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29)

```
Collections.sort(dateList, new Comparator<Date>(){
           public int compare(Date date1, Date date2){
          return date1.after(date2);
        }
      });
```

Comment: So if I have 10 dates in a list, then how can I use this method to get which is the most recent date......!!!

Comment: Thanks alot, Can I use this in Android too??

Comment: You can use `Collections` class and sort your List with *Comparator*, Yes you can use the same in Android too.

Comment: If you have date in milliseconds, put that in string, and pass the same values to compare method. You will get your dates sorted according to milliseconds that way.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 Comparator date_comparator = new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Date date1, Date date2){
    return date1.compareTo(date2);
    }
    };
```

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, this will actually compile and work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Calendar` or `Date` class to do so. Using calendar and Date you can compare two dates like **date1.compare(date2)** or **date.before(date2)** or **date1.after(date2)** such api's are available for your cases.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Collections.reverse(
    new ArrayList<>().add( 
        OffsetDateTime.parse( 
            "Thu Dec 27 11:02:43 GMT+05:30 2012" , 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu" , Locale.US  ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match. By the way, this is a *terrible* format; if you have any control, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats instead.

```
String input = "Thu Dec 27 11:02:43 GMT+05:30 2012" ;

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu" , Locale.US  );
```

Your input strings specify an offset-from-UTC but not a full time zone. So we parse as an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> odt.toString(): 2012-12-27T11:02:43+05:30

`OffsetDateTime` objects already know how to [sort themselves](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)), as they implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

```
List< OffsetDateTime > odts = new ArrayList<>( 3 ) ;
odts.add( odt ) ;
odts.add( odt.plusMinutes( 7 ) ) ;
odts.add( odt.minusMinutes( 21 ) ) ;

Collections.sort( odts ) ;
```

You want the most recent at top of the list, so [sort in reverse order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)).

```
Collections.reverse( odts ) ;  // Reverse-order.
```

To compare individual java.time objects, call the [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#isBefore-java.time.OffsetDateTime-), [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.OffsetDateTime-), and [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.OffsetDateTime-)/[`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) methods.

```
thisOdt.isBefore( thatOdt )
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time (JSR 310) classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

The [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) and [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) classes in Java already have a good API to compare dates.

You can use this to write your own function for sorting the dates.

You can refer [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/).

Comment: here is an example using Calendar Collections.sort(drawings,new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o, Object t1) {
                return ((Drawing)t1).getCalendar().compareTo(((Drawing)o).getCalendar());
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

There is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/Gkemon/3dc6cf0ab33fcf677ef73b0dc352e96b) which will help you. You've just needed to pass unsorted date strings and date pattern in the parameters of `SortedDateGenerator.getSortedDates(List<String> unSortedDate,String datePattern)` 
function then you will get the strings of the sorted date . If you need `Date` object instead then you can modify my code as your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `getSortedDateList` method to get the dates sorted as per your requirement

```
private ArrayList<Date> getSortedDateList(ArrayList<Date> dateList) {
        //Replace year with current year to sort in jan to dec order
        for(int i = 0; i < dateList.size(); i++) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(dateList.get(i));
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
            dateList.set(i, calendar.getTime());
        }
        //Sort all dates in ascending order
        Collections.sort(dateList);
        //Get final index of past dates
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dateList.size(); i++) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(dateList.get(i));
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            today.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
            if (calendar.getTime().after(today.getTime())) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        //New list for storing upcoming dates
        ArrayList<Date> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //Store upcoming dates in new list
        for (int i = index; i < dateList.size(); i++) {
            newList.add(dateList.get(i));
        }
        //Store past dates in new list
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            newList.add(dateList.get(i));
        }
        Collections.copy(dateList, newList);
        return dateList;
    }
```

For example, store some sample dates to array list and call `getSortedDateList` method

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"); // Your date format
        
ArrayList<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Thu May 25 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2000"));
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Tue Apr 18 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021"));
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Wed Jan 27 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 1997"));
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Sat Feb 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2020"));
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Mon Dec 20 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2001"));
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Thu Jun 14 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2009"));
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 1999"));
dateList.add(formatter.parse("Sat Nov 07 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2005"));
        
dateList = getSortedDateList(dateList);
        
for(Date date: dateList) {
    System.out.println(date.toString());
}
```

If current date is `Feb 01 2021`, then the final output will be as shown below

```
Mon Feb 22 00:00:00 IST 2021
Mon Mar 01 00:00:00 IST 2021
Sun Apr 18 00:00:00 IST 2021
Tue May 25 00:00:00 IST 2021
Mon Jun 14 00:00:00 IST 2021
Sun Nov 07 00:00:00 IST 2021
Mon Dec 20 00:00:00 IST 2021
Wed Jan 27 00:00:00 IST 2021
```