# Sort dates from newest to oldest

Tags: android, comparator

I am trying to order some arraylist from **newest date to oldest** date using **comparator**.
But I can`t seem to get it right, the dates are getting sorted but not from newest to oldest.

Any help is appreciated.

Piece of the code involved:

```
public class MyFvModel {

    ...
    private long time;

    public MyFvModel(String fvName, long fvDate, long id) {
        this.fvName = fvName;
        this.fvDate = fvDate;
        this.id = id;
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    ...
    public static Comparator<MyFvModel> DateComparator = new Comparator<MyFvModel>() {

    public int compare(MyFvModel s1, MyFvModel s2) {
        long Date1 = s1.getFvDate();
        long curTime = s2.getTime();

        if (Date1 < curTime)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: did you have a look at the java doc for the [**compare**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method for when to return `-1`, `0` , `1`.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050012/2940733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compare function is wrong. The compare function should return a negative number if s1 should came before s2, 0 if s1 and s2 are equal and a positive number if s1 should came after s2.

Since you want to return the newest to the oldest, you should return a negative number if  s1 is newer than s2, 0 if is equal and a positive number if is older. Your fixed code is:

```
public int compare(MyFvModel s1, MyFvModel s2) {
    long date1 = s1.getFvDate();
    long date2 = s2.getFvDate();

    if (date1 > date2)
        return -1;
    else if(date1 < date2)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
};
```

A more simple version could be:

```
public int compare(MyFvModel s1, MyFvModel s2) {
    long date1 = s1.getFvDate();
    long date2 = s2.getFvDate();
    return date1 - date2;
}
```

Comment: Thx jonathanrz, i was close.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide on which variable you want to order. If you want to order over you `fvDate` then your comparison should always compare `s1.getFvDate()` and `s2.getFvDate()` and not with other variables.