# Java date pattern

Tags: java

i have this string output 'Wed Apr 01 09:50:31 CEST 2015' can anyone tell me what pattern is that . i need it in order to use it in another function.

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {
    String input = "Wed Apr 01 09:50:31 CEST 2015";
    String format = "DD MM hh:mm:ss YYYY"; // i have a wrong format

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = df.parse(input);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println(week);
}
```

any help to figure out the correct format of date pattern in my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937017/how-to-convert-a-date-in-this-format-tue-jul-13-000000-cest-2010-to-a-java-d you have this post with tha same question

Comment: It is `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Answer (score 3):

Solution to your problem is to override default Date locale using

```
SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale) constructor:

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
dateFormat.parse("Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2011");
 System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Solution copy of [How to convert a date in this format (Tue Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2010) to a Java Date (The string comes from an alfresco property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937017/how-to-convert-a-date-in-this-format-tue-jul-13-000000-cest-2010-to-a-java-d)

Comment: Plus one for not forgetting to define `Locale`