# Date parse with Timezone - Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, date

The input date is `Tue Jun 09 07:00:00 SAST 2015`.  I want to parse this to a date so I used

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

Date inputDate = inputFormatter.parse("Tue Jun 09 07:00:00 SAST 2015");
```

This throws a ParseException at offset 20

Comment: It's working for me as-is, I got `inputDate :: Tue Jun 09 10:30:00 IST 2015` .

Comment: Maybe it will only receive time zone IDs in this list:

https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/

Comment: See this answer too:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5937103/481528

Comment: Check if the timezone "Africa/Johannesburg" is supported on your Android device. You can use this code: `System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Johannesburg").getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)); // SAST
` Or inspect `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`