# Converting Twitter4J Date to SQL Date

Tags: java, sql, datetime-format, java.util.date

I have this date format coming from Twitter API: Wed Oct 11 17:30:20 CEST 2017

In Java SQL I need this date format: 2017-10-11 17:30:20

How can i convert the date format to make it possible to insert into database?

This i my code:

```
Date createdAt = message.getCreatedAt();
```

Comment: So, you are saving date as String?

Comment: [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937017/how-to-convert-a-date-in-this-format-tue-jul-13-000000-cest-2010-to-a-java-d) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems `getCreatedAt()` method returns a `java.util.Date` object, so if you need to instantiate a `java.sql.Date` instance to save on your database, you can simply do this:

```
Date createdAt = message.getCreatedAt();
java.sql.Date sqlCreatedAt = new java.sql.Date(createdAt.getTime())
```

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html#getCreatedAt--

Comment: ??? Why is this Answer accepted when it does not address the Question? The Question says it wants a date-time entered into the database, but the `java.sql.Date` class here represents a date-only, lacking the time-of-day portion.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use objects, not strings.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    ZonedDateTime.parse( 
        "Wed Oct 11 17:30:20 CEST 2017" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US ) 
    ).toInstant() 
)
```

## java.time

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. **No need to mess about with mere strings** nor the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `java.sql.Date`/`java.sql.Timestamp`.

Define a formatting pattern for your input. Specify a `Locale` to indicate the human language needed for translating the name of the day and name of the month.

```
String input = "Wed Oct 11 17:30:20 CEST 2017";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US );
```

Parse as a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) given that your input includes a hint about the time zone. Note that your `CEST` is *not* actually a time zone, but `ZonedDateTime` will take a guess at interpreting. Such 3-4 letter pseudo-zones give a hint about the time zone, but are not standardized and are not even unique(!). This, along with the rest of your input string, is a terrible choice of date-time formats. Whenever possible, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats instead.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Generally best to work in UTC. Extract a `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Pass that to your database via [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) supporting JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

If your database column is of the type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` rather than `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, then use a `LocalDateTime` object rather than a `ZonedDateTime`/`Instant`. A [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

## Legacy `java.util.Date`

If your Twitter call actually returned a `java.util.Date` object rather than a String, convert to an Instant and follow the test of the steps seen above.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;  // Convert from troublesome legacy `Date` class to modern `Instant` class.
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: You and I didn’t read the question the same way. I think the OP’s got a `java.util.Date` and wants to insert it into the database (if so, `createdAt.toInstant()` suffices). If on the other hand the question is about parsing `Wed Oct 11 17:30:20 CEST 2017`, it’s a dupe of [How to convert Date.toString back to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431927/how-to-convert-date-tostring-back-to-date)